# Prevent auto-cancellation of redundant pipelines for `master` branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab CI has a feature called [Auto-cancel redundant pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-redundant-pipelines). It's quite useful - if you push a new commit to an MR it will cancel any running pipelines on that MR. That's always what you want.

Unfortunately it doesn't just apply to MRs, it seems like it also auto-cancels CI jobs triggered by commits to `master`. That definitely *isn't* what you want. For example if your CI is relatively slow and your commit rate is high then you'll never have a `master` CI job finish - they'll constantly be cancelled!

There is [an `interruptible` flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#interruptible) that you can apply to pipeline jobs to prevents the entire pipeline being cancelled. As soon as a job runs with this flag set then none of the stages will run. We currently use that like this:

```
default:
  interruptible: true

make_uninterruptible:
  stage: .pre
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  interruptible: false
  script:
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is uninterruptible"
```

I.e. a job that runs ASAP but only if we're on `master`.

This *almost* works. The problem is this:

> A job that has not started yet is always considered interruptible: true, regardless of the job’s configuration. The interruptible configuration is only considered after the job starts.

Sometimes the `make_uninterruptible` job gets delayed a bit, and the entire pipeline is cancelled before it gets a chance to run.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I found [a bug report for this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34221). As seems to be par for the course it's several years old, no workarounds and lots of "A large premium customer is requesting this feature" comments :-D

Answer (score 0):

> A job that has not started yet is always considered interruptible: true, regardless of the job’s configuration

[GitLab 16.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/02/15/gitlab-16-9-released/#expanded-options-for-auto-canceling-pipelines) (February 2024) should address this:

> ### Expanded options for auto-canceling pipelines
>
> Currently, to use the [auto-cancel redundant pipeline feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-redundant-pipelines), you must set jobs that can be cancelled as [`interruptible: true`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#interruptible) to determine whether or not a pipeline can be cancelled. But this only applies to jobs that are actively running when GitLab tries to cancel the pipeline. Any jobs that have not yet started (are in “pending” status) are also considered safe to cancel, regardless of their `interruptible` configuration.
>
> This lack of flexibility hinders users who want more control over which exact jobs can be cancelled by the auto-cancel pipeline feature. To address this limitation, we are pleased to announce the introduction of the `auto_cancel:on_new_commit` keywords with more granular control over job cancellation. If the legacy behavior did not work for you, you now have the option to configure the pipeline to only cancel jobs that are explicitly set with `interruptible: true`, even if they haven’t started yet. You can also set jobs to never be automatically cancelled.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_9/interruptible.png -- Expanded options for auto-canceling pipelines]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#workflowauto_cancelon_new_commit) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/412473).

---

The setting allows for specifying whether pending jobs should be auto-canceled when a new commit is pushed.
To make sure jobs in the `master` branch are not canceled when new commits are made, we should apply this setting in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      auto_cancel:
        on_new_commit: never  # Never auto-cancel pending jobs on new commit for master branch
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      auto_cancel:
        on_new_commit: running  # For non-master branches, auto-cancel only running jobs

job_for_master:
  script:
    - echo "That job runs on master and will not be auto-canceled on new commits."
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  interruptible: false  # Make sure this job is not interruptible

job_for_other_branches:
  script:
    - echo "That job runs on branches other than master and can be auto-canceled if running on new commits."
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  interruptible: true  # That job is interruptible
```

With the `auto_cancel:on_new_commit: never` setting for the `master` branch, you can make sure any jobs queued or pending for the `master` branch will not be auto-canceled when a new commit is pushed.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see how that feature would help achieve what I described.

Comment: @Timmmm I was thinking about the part "it seems like it also auto-cancels CI jobs triggered by commits to master. That definitely isn't what you want". I have edited the answer.